# Is there a way to get a Cursor from a GreenDao Query object?

Tags: android, android-cursor, greendao

I'm trying to implement an `AlphabtIndexer` and the constructor requires a Cursor to the table in the DB.

is there a way to get a Cursor back from a Query object in GreenDao?

Comment: Also checkout lazy list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953168/greendao-listview-all-data-from-entity 
Maybe you want to wrap cursor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have Query object `query` and dao sesssion `daoSession`
you can run:

```
Cursor cursor = daoSession.getDatabase().rawQuery(query.getSql(), query.getParameters());
```

Comment: Query object don't have `getSql()` or `getParameters()`

Comment: sorry, it is my bad. it was a custom code in [our version](https://github.com/path/greenDAO/blame/master/DaoCore/src/de/greenrobot/dao/AbstractQuery.java). you can easily add it the same way.

Comment: Any one know why the sql field isnt accessible with a getter from the original code?

Comment: The new 2.1 release will have a fully working QueryCursor builder.

Answer (score 3):

GreenDao 2.1, queryBuilder offers a buildCursor() function

```
session.getMyObjectDao().queryBuilder()
        .where(MyObjectDao.Properties.Locale.eq("en")))
        .buildCursor().forCurrentThread().query()
```

Answer (score -1):

With GreenDao 2.1 you can create a QueryBuilder object then just call buildCursor().query() on the object to return a cursor.

```
DBUserDao userDao = daoSession.getDBUserDao();
QueryBuilder<DBUser> queryBuilder = userDao.queryBuilder().where(DBUserDao.Properties.Phone_number.eq("XYZ"));
Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.buildCursor().query();
```